# This photo has light dot bokeh in front of the subject, seemingly coming from the sun. How was this done, or how can the effect be achieved?

Tags: bokeh

Credit:

https://www.instagram.com/p/CONgtDuFozh/
ins: iwakurashiori

[image]

This photo has light dot bokeh in front of the subject, seemingly coming from the sun. How was this done, or how can the effect be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit of black-belt Google-fu & Google Translate found the definitive answer, from the photographer themself.

It's an in-camera double exposure (proving my original theory wrong;)

> It was so beautiful that I used the features of New FM2 for multiple exposure. I took a picture of a person first, and by overlaying particles of light on the dark part, I captured the beauty of the light reflected on the surface of the water.

Via Google Translate from [nikostop.nikon-image.com](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://nicostop.nikon-image.com/entry/travel/film/2021/03/26/1)

Comment: Well I did try my Google-fu before posting the question. But your Google-fu seems much better ;) P.S. just spent 15min learning about double exposure, fun stuff

Answer (score 2):

Nice image.

Although Tetsujin has broken the illusion and ruined our creativity by providing a fact check inquery ☺️...

A similar effect could be done by spraying some water drops or another liquid on a sheet of glass in front of the lens.

Of course, you would not have the hexagonal shape but a rounded one.

You could play a bit with the distance between the lens and the glass, or even the angle of it.

Comment: I will give that a try. Does the glass material / thickness matter? And question: why would I get a rounded bokeh? (well my lens does give round bokeh but I'm searching for a 6/7 bladed lens now..)

Comment: It would not be a bokeh, it would be a lens flare sort of. In reality an out-of-focus droplet.